# "ItemAvailability" value for factory direct (non stocking distribution) items?

Tags: schema.org, ecommerce

Anyone know the best way to communicate [`ItemAvailability`](https://schema.org/ItemAvailability) in cases where the item cannot be stocked, but the item is available direct from the manufacturer/factory?

In other words, sometime a company might offer a product only via authorized retailers but disallow any retailers and distributors from stocking the item. So, the retailers e-commerce website can't accurately say [`InStock`](https://schema.org/InStock) or [`OutOfStock`](https://schema.org/OutOfStock)?  [`OnlineOnly`](https://schema.org/OnlineOnly) would seem useless to the end-user in this case?

> **Enumeration members**
>
> - `Discontinued`
> - `InStock`
> - `InStoreOnly`
> - `LimitedAvailability`
> - `OnlineOnly`
> - `OutOfStock`
> - `PreOrder`
> - `PreSale`
> - `SoldOut`

Comment: What’s different for the end customer in such a case? The customer goes to the retailer site and orders the item -- does the customer even know (or: need to know) that the retailer (instead of taking it from their own stock) gets the item from the manufacturer?

Comment: `FactoryDirect` is what I'm after - I think. In this case, it's kind of an open secret for many larger buyers that retailers get this family of products thru multiple channels and either via 'distribution' or 'factory'. So, they would have interest in whether or not it's available via distribution channels (and qty's). Factory is often back-ordered when distributors have stock. ...I ended up just going with `OnlineOnly` as it seems closest to what I'm after.